# Cron job to run Selenium 2 test Suite

Tags: java, cron, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have an ant script that checks out all our projects from SVN, and then builds the project, deploys the WAR files and runs the Selenium tests. Unfortunately, when running the shell script via `cron`, it does not open the Browser.

Throws up the error :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 6.88 seconds
Build info: version: &apos;2.21.0&apos;, revision: &apos;16552&apos;, time: &apos;2012-04-11 19:09:00&apos;
System info: os.name: &apos;Linux&apos;, os.arch: &apos;amd64&apos;, os.version: &apos;2.6.37.6-0.9-desktop&apos;, java.version: &apos;1.6.0_26&apos;
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:175)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.&lt;init&gt;(RemoteWebDriver.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.&lt;init&gt;(ChromeDriver.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.&lt;init&gt;(ChromeDriver.java:110)
    at com.integration.SetUp.testLogin(SetUp.java:52)
</error>
```

I did add `export DISPLAY=:0` to the shell script being used.

```
export ANT_HOME=/home/user/CCBuild/apache-ant-1.8.2

export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
export DISPLAY=:0
echo $ANT_HOME
cd CCBuild
ant -v -f build-all.xml
```

Even then, it throws up the error. As of now, I can't use Jenkins to run the suite, I need to get this `cron` job working.

Comment: where have you entered the cron job? which user?

Comment: Normal user. Entered it as crontab -e . Its like  0 12 * * * sh ant.sh

Comment: has this user a running x-server? or at least the permission to use a x-server session from an other user?

Comment: It does not run as root. But it says that it is using chrome binary at  /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome  and I can run that  to open chrome , without being root

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old... but I was having the same issue.  I solved this by setting the variables in crontab... add to the top of the cron DISPLAY=:0